# Strange behavior when using transition with li

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I created navigation and it worked well. But when I use transition `<li>` I don't know tell what's exactly but when I hover li item and mouse out it, then ul sibling doesn't work properly.

http://codepen.io/thehung1724/full/gmlfE/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"> <a class="toggleMenu" href="#">Menu</a>

    <ul class="nav">
        <li>    <a href="#" class="parent">Shoes</a>

            <ul>
                <li>    <a href="#" class="parent">Womens</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li class=""><a href="#">Sandals</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wedges</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Heels</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Flats</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#" class="parent">Mens</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Loafers</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Formal</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#" class="parent">Shirts</a>

            <ul>
                <li>    <a href="#" class="parent">Mens</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dress Shirts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tank Tops</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#" class="parent">Womens</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blouses</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dress Shirts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tunics</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Camisoles</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>    <a href="#">Shipping Info</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS (LESS)**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul,
ol{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.container {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
}

.toggleMenu{
    display: none;
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav{
    background: #175e4c;
    width: 100%;

    &:before, &:after{
        content: ""; 
        display: table;
    }

    &:after{
        clear: both;
    }

    > li{
        float: left;

        &.hover > ul{
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    li{
        ul{
            visibility:hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
            transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        }

        li{
            a{
                background: #1d7a62;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 100;
                border-top: 1px solid #175e4c;
            }

            &.hover ul{
                visibility: visible;
                opacity: 1; 
                left: 100%;
                top: 0;
            }

            li a{
                background: #249578;
                z-index: 200;
                border-top: 1px solid #1d7a62;
            }
        }
    }

    ul{
        width: 9em;
        position: relative;
    }

    a{
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .toggleMenu{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .active {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav{
        width: 100%;

        > li{
            border-top: 1px solid #104336;
            float: none;
        }

        > li.hover > ul , li li.hover ul{
            position: static;
        }

        .more{
            color: #fff;
            width: 20%;
            float: right;
            padding: 8px 15px;
            margin: 2px 0;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 200;
            position: relative;
        }

        ul{
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("parent");
        };
    })

    $(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".nav").toggle();
    });
    adjustMenu();
})

$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    adjustMenu();
});

var adjustMenu = function() {
    if (ww < 768) {
    // if "more" link not in DOM, add it
    if (!$(".more")[0]) {
    $('<div class="more"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></div>').insertBefore($('.parent')); 
    }
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
        if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".nav").hide();
        } else {
            $(".nav").show();
        }
        $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(".nav li a.parent").unbind('click');
    $(".nav li .more").unbind('click').bind('click', function() {

            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
        });
    } 
    else if (ww >= 768) {
    // remove .more link in desktop view
    $('.more').remove(); 
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");
        $(".nav").show();
        $(".nav li").removeClass("hover");
        $(".nav li a").unbind('click');
        $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
            // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
            $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider narrowing down the code to a smaller set to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your talking about how the drill down appears below the main drop down while it's fading in, and then snaps into position once it's fully opaque, correct?

The reason is that you've specified the transitions for your uls to target 'all' properties. Since you don't specify initial values for top and left, this means that on hover those values will attempt transition from auto (the default) to 100% and 0, which isn't valid, resulting in the sudden jump.

You can fix it two ways: Limit the transitions to only affect opacity, or define the top and left for the ul regardless of the presence of the hover class.

Personally I prefer the defining static properties independent of hover state:

```
.nav li li ul{
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

But at the same time, targeting opacity will give you better performance than all, and will prevent any additional side effects if you add more properties in the future. If it were me, I'd implement both solutions.

Working pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hqEew

Comment: My opacity effect doesn't work. Could you help me again?

Comment: Fixed myself. Thank you :)